# Under what circumstances can a JSON encoded array become a string?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have some PHP 5 code that is similar to this:

```
$result = myFunction(...);  // return false, or doit action
$reply = array();
if ($result) {
   $reply['doit'] =  $result;
   $reply['status'] = "a status html string";
} else {
   $reply['content'] = "Some html text";
   $reply['menu'] = "Some other html text";
   $reply['status'] = "a different status html string";
}
return $reply;
```

The caller includes the fragment

```
$reply = somefunction();
echo json_encode($reply);
```

This reply is then sent to the client, where jquery passes it to my function

```
function handleReply(reply) {
    if (reply.doit) {
        handle action
    }
    if (reply.content) document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=reply.content;
    if (reply.menu) document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML=reply.menu;
    if (reply.status) document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=reply.status;
}
```

What I have been struggling with is that, when the doit branch of the if statement is executed, ($result is a string) the reply given to me by jquery is a string. When the content/menu/status side is taken ($result is false) then reply is an object.

I have added a second second index to the array and the result is the same. Although all strings are ASCII I have tried passing them through UTF8_encode. I have changed the name of the 'doit' index from 'action' in case that was triggering some behaviour in jquery.

Just to be clear, the reply, when it is wrong is (for example).

```
"{"doit":"obj=session&act=show&ID=3","status":"<p>Nic: Ian<br\/>Reseller: Coachmaster.co.uk<br\/>Status: SysAdmin <\/p>"}"
```

Which is a string. I expected:

```
{"doit":"obj=session&act=show&ID=3","status":"<p>Nic: Ian<br\/>Reseller: Coachmaster.co.uk<br\/>Status: SysAdmin <\/p>"}
```

Which is an object/array. This is also what my logging showed as being echoed.

I'm using php5.4.3 under windows 7 and Apache and php 5.3.10 under linux and nginx with the same results. jquery is version v1.7.2 in both. Also loaded is jQuery UI - v1.10.3 - 2013-07-02.

If it is a bug in jquery, its a very strange one. How can I prove it?

Comment: JSON *is* a string.  You need to parse/decode it.  You can add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax` call, or use `var obj = $.parseJSON(reply);`.

Comment: Programming rule #1: Whenever you find yourself thinking that you might have found a bug in a major library, stop and consider the likelihood of it being a bug in jQuery. And of nobody else noticing it before you. It's pretty unlikely. No impossible but unlikely. Always start with the assumption that it's something you're doing wrong.

Comment: Where do you get the logging? Php, firebug, inside handleReply()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you rely on jQuery autodetection. Try:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the string into JavaScript, you'd have to `eval()` it to turn it into a JSON object:

```
var reply_json = eval( reply );
```

Then you can access `reply_json.content`, `reply_json.menu`, and so on.

Obviously be careful about what it is you're eval'ing, make sure it's from a trusted source and so forth.

Comment: jQuery handles the conversion safely and automatically.

Comment: All `eval` and no [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) make Jack a dull boy.

Comment: These comments are true.. I've suggested that @Wouter Neuteboom's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

jQuery.parseJSON()

Comment: I believe his answer is safer to use than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `$.getJSON()` jquery method or `$.ajax()`?

When using `$.ajax()` method, if you don't specify `dataType: "json"` option when you are making ajax request, jQuery will use "intelligent guess" (by searching for response MIME type) to figure how to interpret server response (xml, html, plain, json object...). If it is unable to figure that automatically it will assume response is plain text and regular string will be returned in success handle.

You should use either `$.getJSON()` or specify `dataType: "json"`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "....",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(reply) { // success handle
        // if not specifying dataType: "json",
        // and if not using response headers to specify MIME type "application/json", 
        // reply will not be object but a string!
    }
});
```

or, as Marek posted in his answer, specify MIME type in response headers.